# Adjust logging level for Kafka-python admin client

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka, metadata, kafka-python

While creating the `KafkaAdminClient`

```
    client = KafkaAdminClient(bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers,
                          security_protocol=security_protocol,
                          sasl_mechanism=SASL_MECHANISM,
                          sasl_plain_username=username,
                          sasl_plain_password=password,
                          )
```

there are a lot of `debug` and `info` logs that are generated like:

```
 kafka.client [DEBUG]- [client_async.py:279 -   _conn_state_change()] - Node bootstrap-0 connected
 kafka.protocol.parser [DEBUG]- [parser.py:59 -         send_request()] - Sending request MetadataRequest_v0(topics=[])
```

Is there a config that would allow switching off `DEBUG` and `INFO` logs and only show `WARN or ERROR` logs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It uses the standard `logging` library and the client side handler is named `kafka`:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('kafka')
logger.setLevel(logging.WARN)
```

That should configure the `kafka-python` library log level.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to silence certain kafka logs over others you can fetch loggers for the specific sources listed next to your log levels. For example, this helped when my consumer was flooding our system with fetcher.py logs, but I wanted to avoid impacting the logs for other kafka uses.

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('kafka.consumer.fetcher').setLevel(logging.INFO)
```